# Cross browser JavaScript implementation of xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I wrote a small, cross browser compliant implementation of xhr requests in client JavaScript that **closely follows** the jQuery `$.ajax()` API and standards. The goal is to keep the `xhr()` very small in size, yet cover most common xhr scenarios and needs.

I'd like code review for performance, general best practice, and the most browser support **(IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari)**.

```
function xhr(options) {
    if(!options) {
        options = {};
    }

    var url = options.url ? options.url : window.location.href;
    var method = options.method ? options.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';
    var data = options.data ? JSON.stringify(options.data) : null;
    var contentType = (typeof options.contentType !== 'undefined') ? options.contentType : null;
    var headers = (options.headers && typeof options.headers === 'object') ? options.headers : {};
    var username = options.username ? options.username : null;
    var password = options.password ? options.password : null;
    var timeout = options.timeout ? options.timeout : 0;
    var withCredentials = (typeof options.withCredentials !== 'undefined') ? options.withCredentials : false;
    var onSuccess = (options.onSuccess && typeof options.onSuccess === 'function') ? options.onSuccess : null;
    var onError = (options.onError && typeof options.onError === 'function') ? options.onError : null;
    var onTimeout = (options.onTimeout && typeof options.onTimeout === 'function') ? options.onTimeout : null;

    var _xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    _xhr.open(method, url, true, username, password);

    _xhr.timeout = timeout;

    _xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    if(contentType) {
        _xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    } else if(contentType !== false && data) {
        _xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    }

    if(withCredentials) {
        _xhr.withCredentials = withCredentials;
    }

    for (var key in headers) {
        _xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
    }

    _xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            var responseHeaders = this.getAllResponseHeaders();

            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                if(onSuccess) {
                    onSuccess(this.responseText, this.status, responseHeaders, this);
                }
            } else {
                if(onError) {
                    onError(this, this.status, responseHeaders);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    if(onTimeout) {
        _xhr.ontimeout = onTimeout;
    }

    _xhr.send(data);
    _xhr = null;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
xhr({
    url: "http://foo.bar"
});

xhr({
    url: "http://foo.bar/create",
    method: "POST",
    data: 'foo=bar'
});

xhr({
    url: "http://foo.bar/create",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    headers: {
        "X-Key": "Value"
    },
    timeout: 5000,
    onSuccess: function(response, statusCode, responseHeaders, xhr) {     
    },
    onError: function(xhr, statusCode, responseHeaders) {
    },
    onTimeout: function(event) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is a new API for AJAX called [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It even has a polyfill. [It even has a polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for older browsers which looks to me like its already doing what you aim to do.

But anyways, onto your code.

I see you have a long list of ternaries to set values or a default to the options. Instead of that, create an object hosting your defaults, and use `Object.assign` to merge it and the user config into an object. This throws away the need for doing a ternary/if-else on your code by providing sensible defaults.

```
var defaults = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: window.location.href,
  username: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  withCredentials: undefined
};

var mergedOptions = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

var _xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

_xhr.open(mergedOptions.method, mergedOptions.url, true, mergedOptions.username, mergedOptions.password);

_xhr.withCredentials = mergedOptions.withCredentials
```

For calling the callbacks, consider using `call` with a context of `null`. This way, the callback has no assumptions on what the context is and code doesn't accidentally bind something to the global scope.

Alternatively, consider returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from your function. This way, it acts more like jQuery and the standard `fetch`.

```
function xhr(options){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // setup XHR

    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) resolve(this.responseText, this.status, responseHeaders, this);
    else reject(this, this.status, responseHeaders);

    // send XHR
  });
}

xhr({...}).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It appears `Object.assign()` is not widely supported. The most important thing is code that is cross browser compliant. The same with using `Promises`

Comment: Also, `fetch()` and the GitHub polyfill looks awesome, but need at least IE9 support.